# php & mysql loop through records for limited number to be in multiple box

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

In this table there are more than 60 records.
I want to preview the records into four boxes - for each box 15 records.
Basically, doing a pagination is easy, but I want it like that to be in a slide show.
My code right now is:

```
$mysql_employers = "SELECT * FROM data LIMIT ".$page.",".$limiter."";
$query_employers = $dblink->query($mysql_employers) or die("employers failed!");
$employers_link = array();
while($employers = $query_employers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$employers_link[]=$employers;
}
$employers = new Smarty;
$employers->caching = false;
$employers->assign("employers",$employers_link);
$employers->display("default/employers.tpl");
```

$page is the page number and $limiter is the limit per page, which is 15.
The smarty template code is

```
<div class="employers-box">
{$foreach $employers as $emp}
<div class="employers">
    <div class="employerphoto"><img src="{$emp.photo}"></div>
    <div class="employername"><a href="viewemplyer.php?employer={$emp.id}">{$emp.name}</a></div>
</div>
{/foreach}
</div>
```

What can I change in the code to make it shown in the page as four boxes (with 15 employers for each box) instead of being in pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant way, but you could just use `if` statements to check when the threshold is reached to close one `div` and open the next.

In your example, your array is numeric so we can use the index `key` as a counter.
Read up about that on [the smarty page here](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/language.function.foreach.tpl).

You can also use [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to have just one simple if statement.

```
<div class="employers-box">
{foreach key=$counter item=$emp from=$employers}
  {if $counter % 15 === 0}
    <div id="employers-box-{$counter / 15}" class="employers">
  {/if}
  <div class="employer">
    <div class="employerphoto"><img src="{$emp.photo}"></div>
    <div class="employername"><a href="viewemplyer.php?employer={$emp.id}">{$emp.name}</a>  
  </div>
  {if $counter % 15 === 0}
    </div>
  {/if}
{/foreach}
</div>
```